# How to decrease a column by some variable amount?

Tags: java, sql, database, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am trying to decrease the value of a column by some amount. In other words, the column is of type double and i want to decrease it by "total" amount. If the initial value was 100, now it has to be 100-total. Here is my code:

```
PreparedStatement checkDB1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("update accounts set balance=balance-? where iban=?");
checkDB1.setString(1, total);
```

This gives a syntax error saying:

```
 reason: actual argument double cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
```

so how can i write this query?  Thanks

Comment: Please note that this is the textbook example of things that can go wrong in a concurrent database application :) (keywords transactions and serializability and the like ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error is the type being used to set the `PreparedStatement` parameter is incorrect as indicated by the error message

```
PreparedStatement checkDB1 = 
       con.prepareStatement("update accounts set balance=balance - ? where iban=?");
checkDB1.setDouble(1, total);
            ^^^
```

Notice also the `PreparedStatement` cast has been removed as unnecessary

Comment: And also mind the actual datatype of the column in the table , before setting the value using `setXXX()` method !

Comment: thanks, i thought this solution also but wondered whether there is easier way without needing to read the balance first

Comment: @MatBailie noting at all except for the type being used for the parameter